# How I can programmatically set select value from ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have select and ajax data. How can I programmatically set select value from ajax?
try

```
$('.select').on('change', function() {}).val(1).trigger('change');
$(".select [value='10']").attr("selected","selected");
$('.select').trigger("change");
```

and last one

```
var evt = $.Event("select2:select", {params: {data: data, startend: startend}});
$('.select').val(1).trigger(evt).trigger("change");
```

doesn't work.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic

Comment: assuming `.select` is your select box, you can use `$('.select').val(1)` to set the value of the select box to 1. To also trigger the `onChange` event, you need to chain `.trigger('change')`. So the whole line to set the value of the select box would be `$('.select').val(1).trigger('change');`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'doesn't work' ? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Thank you, guys! Love all! Solve like this var evt = $.Event("select2:select", {params: {data: data}});
    $this.trigger(evt).trigger("change");
    $this.append('<option value="' + data.id + '" selected>' + data.name + '</option>').attr("selected","selected").trigger("change");

Comment: why doesn't work standart man doc? ) & no errors)))